# Does Monte Carlo Localization need a predefined map?

Tags: localization, slam, mapping

So I'm doing some reading on Monte Carlo Localization, and it sounds like the approach is based on using a predefined map, but I just need to make sure (because I haven't read anywhere that it absolutely needs a predefined map). I just want to make 100% sure that my understanding is correct:

Does it absolutely need a predefined map?

[maybe I need to add the below stuff as another question, but here goes nothing]
And what other localization approaches are there that don't need a predefined map? So far I've only read about SLAM (which sounds to me like a general approach instead of a specific implementation).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as defined in literature, all *localization* requires a prior map.

This is because the goal of localization is to *localize* a robot with respect to some feature. If you don't know where the feature is, you can't know where the robot is.

If you are *uncertain* about the features, then you are doing *Simultaneous Localization and Mapping* (SLAM).